# Rails: stringing together multiple has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, rails-activerecord

I have three models which look something like this:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
end

Class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

Now I want to get all the votes associated with a user's comments like so:

```
@user.comments.votes
```

But this throws the error:

```
undefined method `votes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3f6f8a0>
```

This seems like it should work, but I suspect ActiveRecord is coughing on the deeper has_many relationship. I've hacked together an SQL query that gets the desired results, but I suspect there's a cleaner way using purely ActiveRecord. Any tips?

Comment: what is replies? comments mb?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo. Yep, that should have read as comments.

Comment: ok, and why do you need it? and where - in a view?

Comment: In this instance, it's purely for data management. Specifically, I'm getting a score for how well-liked a user's comments are. At the moment, the code looks something like this: self.comments.votes.sum(:value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [has_many :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)

In your case it would be

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes, :through => :comments
end

Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
end

Class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

And then simply get the votes with

```
@user.votes
```

Comment: Got a lot of good answers, but this seems the cleanest. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Vote.joins(comment: :user).where(users: {id: @user.id})
```